# Force Google Places Autocomplete results to include a country and city

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to parse a city and country from an "Enter your location" textbox. Google Places Autocomplete is good at retrieving locations, but not every result has a country and a city (e.g. typing in "Russia" will show "Russia" as the top result, which lists no city). Whatever location the user type is saved, but the city and country portions need to be stored separately.

Is there a way to force every autocomplete result to contain both a city and a country, BUT not limit it to only those two? (e.g. typing in "Russia" would show "Moscow, Russia" or "115 X Street, Moscow, Russia", etc.)

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <title>Place Autocomplete</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&amp;language=en" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    
      var autocomplete; 
      var place;

      function initialize() 
      {
        var options       = {types: ['(cities)']};
        var input         = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        
        autocomplete  = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
          fillInPlace();
        });
      }

      function fillInPlace() {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        var $address = $(place['adr_address']);
        $('#resultTextField').val($address.text());
      }

      $(document).on('ready', function(){
          $("#searchTextField").on('focusout', function(e){
              setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#searchTextField").val('');
              }, 1000);
          });
      })
      
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class='form'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="searchTextField">City</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <input id="searchTextField" type="text" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="on" class='form-control pull-left' style='width:40%; margin-right:3px;'>
        <input id="resultTextField" type="text" placeholder="" autocomplete="on" class='form-control pull-left' disabled='disabled' style='width:55%'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```